# record audio file and upload it to the server in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, native

i am very much sure that you guys have seen whats app recording feature , so i want to make module very much like this, i am making this app in react native hope you guys provide me proper solution

for this first i need to record file in cache or local directory then by getting uri of my audio file i have to store it to the s3

this is my plan,  so give me suggestion is this good idea or there is another way that i could do it more efficiently

suggesst me the library for react native to record file and save it to the local and upload it to the amazon s3

Comment: `.aggregate()` is never supported on the client (in minimongo). It is supported on the server via [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate) If you want to a join to, for example, show all the orders that involve a product, then you can also use [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite)

Answer (score 1):

The Mongo `.aggregate()` method is not supported, the reason being that MiniMongo does not support everything, so in order to get uniformity between client and server code, not all mongo methods are available.

There is, however, a way to do it using this package: https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate

Basically it exposes the `.aggregate()` method for you

Comment: thanks for this but i am having another problem see the details of above two collection  one is products collection and another is invoice collection i have to match product's _id field  to invoice's product's _id field.

Answer (score -1):

There is a package called collection helpers, but it doesn't work great for large data sets.

This requirement is something that is easy to do in a SQL database, and often it's easier to create yourself a small mysql database to act as a data warehouse and run your reporting. You'll need to update the database on say a daily basis, but that should be pretty quick to run. You could even run it every hour, depending on data volumes and system loading.

Another way is to write some Mongo scripts that do some kind of transformation of your data into other documents that you can use for reporting.

Depending on how much of this you need, you can decide on which way to go.